# ApexPages.PageReference redirect issue when in url # symbol

Tags: pagereference, redirect

We started to have redirect issue, when added to url # symbol.
So on backend, apex provides redirect to another page:

```
public ApexPages.PageReference submitRequestAction() {
   //some logic here
   ApexPages.PageReference retVal = new ApexPages.PageReference(this.returnUrl);
   retVal.setRedirect(true);

   return retVal;
}
```

On previous page (original page, where we want to return) was encoded in javascript with using EcmaScript.encodeURIComponent() method to (this is what i see in browser):

```
https%3A%2F%2ForgId%2Fapex%2FvfPageName%3Fforward%3D1%23!%2Fopportunity%2FopportunityId
```

then in apex ctrl with debugging i check, that i still have correct url, as this.returnUrl is:

```
https://orgId/apex/vfPageName?forward=1#!/opportunity/opportunityId
```

So when i click button, which fires submitRequestAction() im redirecting to original page with url:

```
https://orgId/apex/vfPageName?forward=1
```

We lost everything starting from # symbol.

I fixed that in vf page with adding javascript, which still using returnUrl from apex controller, but now we are avoiding Pagereference and it works fine:

```
<script>
    function returnButtonAction() {
       window.location.href = '{!returnUrl}';
    }
</script>

<apex:commandButton immediate="true" value="{!$Label.Button_Cancel}" oncomplete="returnButtonAction();return false;" />
```

I can live with this solution, but i still dont know how to fix it in apex controller.
So would appreciate if you help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the reason is an old API version of controller. I changed it from 26 to 38 and now it works

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it is working for me. Please check in different browser to see if it is a browser specific issue.

Controller

```
public class RedirectController {
    public PageReference submitRequestAction() {
        String returnUrl = '/apex/vfPageName?forward=1#!/opportunity/006i000000Hlb7u';
        System.debug('returnUrl '+returnUrl);
        PageReference retVal = new PageReference(returnUrl);
        retVal.setRedirect(true);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectController" action="{!submitRequestAction}" >
</apex:page>
```

VF vfPageName

```
<apex:page >
    Hello World!
</apex:page>
```

Screen

[image]

Comment: I tried, i put into pagereference  encoded url: https%3A%2F%2ForgId%2Fapex%2FvfPageName%3Fforward%3D1%23!%2FsomeCustomObj%2Fid   But then when i click return button i have error: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.

Comment: @Cooler Sorry for the overlook. I checked your code and it is working for me without any changes. Please check if it is a browser issue.

Comment: This is crazy, i checked also on testPage, it didnt work, then i changed API version of controller from 26 to 38 and now it works))))

Comment: Good to know you solved it. Put your findings as an answer and accept it so that somebody can find it useful.